# Javascript and HTML data model and presentation model design question

Tags: javascript, html, dom

so I've been working on a project in Javascript that takes in objects the user provides and represents them in HTML.  Right now they are represented in memory as an array, and in the display as a separate array.  After integrating some code changes, problems have arisen in that the display array seems to be having troubles removing it's contents, thus things that should be removed don't disappear from the view.

Declaring lists:

```
this.divList = gDocument.getElementById( element );
this.objectList = [];
```

Adding an object to the lists:

```
addObject = function (address, type){
    var newDiv = gDocument.createElement("div");
    this.divList.appendChild( newDiv );

    var d = this.createObject( newDiv, address, type );

    if (undefined != d)
    {
        this.objectList.push(d);
    }
 }
```

The divList accurately reflects the objectList until any changes are made to the objectList at runtime.  When restarted, the lists are in sync once again.  When I tried to fix it, things were very complicated.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to design such an idea (the object model and the graphical representation).  Any comments would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: This is a bit vague... you need to supply specific examples of `what a divList looks like`, `what an objectList looks like` and `how you render your divList` for the best results.

Comment: In theory though, a divList and objectList may end up disappearing with a different design anyway.  I'm more looking for design suggestions for the idea of a Javascript object model and a graphical representation in HTML. Keeping everything I use intact feels like it would defeat the purpose of having a new design, since I feel like it wouldn't make anything simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question vagueness aside, my recommendation would be to store one list, not two, in memory. Each list element is an object with all the necessary data you need *for that particular abstract "object"* (the ones that "the user provides"). Something like this:

```
this.divList = gDocument.getElementById(element);
this.masterList = [];
var i,
    len = this.divList.length;
for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
{
    this.masterList.push({
        elt: this.divList[i],
        obj: /* however you'd create the object in this.objectList  */
    });
}
```

---

*Edit*: your `addObject` function would be changed to something like this:

```
addObject = function (address, type)
{
    var newDiv = gDocument.createElement("div"),
        newObj = {elt: newDiv,
                  obj: this.createObject(newDiv, address, type)};
    this.masterList.push(newObj);
    this.divList.appendChild(newDiv);
 }
```

You should store a reference to the HTML element that you're `appendChild()`ing to. You're already doing this - but when you need to manipulate the individual elements (say, remove one), use the `masterList` instead:

```
removeObject = function (i)
{
    var toRemove = this.masterList.splice(i, 1);
    if (toRemove)
    {
        this.divList.removeChild(toRemove.elt);
    }
}
```

See also [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: So I take it elt is supposed to represent element?  So if I understand correctly, I push an object with both an element (HTML representation) and the object.  However, if I'm only supposed to store one list then why is divList still there?

Comment: @user: yes, that is what I mean. `divList` is there because I assumed that you needed to read the elements out of the HTML (I didn't see your question edit before). In light of your edit, `divList` is not necessary.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  I will probably try to implement this at some point then.